# How I can put mask Date and Time in TexBoxFor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with ASP.Net MVC4 wiht view engine Razor. I like put mask date and time in TexBoxFor I installed for nugget jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js and add in the view

```
(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FechaDen").mask("99/99/9999");
        $("#HoraDen").mask("99:99:99");
    });
```

But I have this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mask'
How I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have forgotted to reference the `jquery.maskedinput` plugin in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js")"></script>
```

Make sure that the path is correct and that the plugin is actually situated in this folder. Use the Network tab of a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug to ensure that there are no 404 errors with your script references.

Also make sure that you have added this script inclusion **after** jQuery. Be careful because in the ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Project Template, the `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file renders jquery as a bundle at the end of the DOM:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

So if you are putting this reference inside your view make sure that this happens inside the `scripts` section:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#FechaDen").mask("99/99/9999");
        $("#HoraDen").mask("99:99:99");
    </script>
}
```

Also notice that since this script is now at the end of the DOM I have gotten rid of the `$(document).ready` call which is no longer necessary (and which you got wrong in the code you have shown because you forgot to prefix it with a `$`).